# Login php if else condition for 2 database table

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hi everyone i think this is good question for everone.

I am try to make a login page. But i have one problem. **I have 2 users table in my database** . **First users table is for normal user** and **second users table is for vip user**.

Under the code using for normal user. i want to make  if email and password is for vip user then open **vip_user_profile.php** if not email and password is vip user then check the normal users table if there is a email and password then open **normal_user_profile.php** how can i do this. Is anyone can help me ?

What i can add a code in my login php code ?

My code is this.

```
<?php  
 include("includes/connect.php");

 if(isset($_POST['login'])){

   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $password = $_POST['pass'];

    $check_user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE password='$password' AND email='$email'";

     $run = mysql_query($check_user);

     if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0) {

        echo"<script>window.open('normal_user_profile.php','_self')</script>";

     }
     else {
       echo"<script>alert('email or password is incorrect!')";

     }
   } 
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: I sincerely hope that you do not store actual passwords, but hashes instead. Other question, why not just have one user table and add a user type column to it, indicating whether a user is a normal user, a VIP user or some unknown future type user?

Comment: Swicth from mysql_* (which is a deprecated method) to preferably PDO or mysqli_*.

Comment: Why not using one table and giving one more field for access level.

Comment: *Do not* store passwords in plain text.  There is *no* reason to *ever* do that.  Repeat after me, ***never store passwords in plain text***.

Comment: @MawiaHL because i have 2 registerform

Comment: You can refer to one table using different forms.

Comment: @David Change that to **never store passwords**. No encrypted passwords either.

Comment: @EcoWebtr: That's not a reason to use two separate tables.  Basically your database design is wrong.  A user is a single type of entity and belongs on a single table.  Attributes which describe a user can go on that table, or on a separate table with a foreign key to that table.  Expanding further, users can have "roles" which would go in a separate table with a many-to-many relationship to the users table.

Comment: @GolezTrol: I agree with not storing encrypted passwords, since encryption isn't the same thing as hashing.  But storing hashed passwords is acceptable and commonly used.  (You need to compare the entered password to *something* after all.)  For many applications, off-loading the authentication can work as well (such as "login with Facebook"), but not for all applications.

Comment: @David Of course. You can store hashes. A hash is not a password. :)

Comment: @David I have 2 register form. first register form is for vip user second register form is for normal user. There are different type. for example normal user register form has no business_name, male female.

Comment: @EcoWebtr: That doesn't justify storing usernames/passwords (user-level info) in two separate tables.  What you're describing are attributes which are attached to a user, not separate types of users.  Those attributes can be stored in lots of different ways, but the common functionality of the username and password used solely for authentication purposes belongs on a single table.  Just because you designed it incorrectly doesn't mean it was *supposed* to be designed incorrectly.

Comment: @GolezTrol I have 2 register form. first register form is for vip user second register form is for normal user. There are different type. for example normal user register form has no business_name, male female.

Comment: @David I Can not at different tables or input method.

Comment: @EcoWebtr: The fact is, there is *a lot* wrong with your code.  Your database design is wrong (no matter how vehemently you defend it), you're wide open to SQL injection attacks, you're using deprecated libraries with known flaws, and you're storing sensitive information in a dangerous and irresponsible way.  There's *a lot* to be fixed here.  For the question at hand, if you *insist* on storing the same data in two different tables then just make two separate SQL queries, one for each table.  Aside from that, there's way too much to fix here than one Stack Overflow answer could provide.

Comment: @David owww i understand.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on storing information in two tables, you can still get the data using one query. There are many ways to do that, but here's one that you might find interesting:

```
select
  sum(usertype) as usercheck
from
  ( select nu.username, nu.password, 1 as usertype 
    from NormalUser nu
  union all 
    select vu.username, vu.password, 2 
    from VipUser vu
) u
where
  u.username = '$username' and 
  u.password = '$password'
```

This query will return a single integer field, which can have either of these values:

- null: No combination exists for username/password
- 1: User is a normal user
- 2: User is a VIP user
- 3: Both tables contain a user with the same password.

Note that in cases of 1 and 2, it is still possible that the same username exists, but with a different password.

Now, to solve that, you can put all users in one table and give them a user type. You can make a lot of extra columns that you can leave empty. If you really want to store that information in a separate table (and there are good arguments for that), you can still create one table with basic user information, such as uername and password. Then, in the VipUsers table, you don't store username and password, but only store the id of the user and the additional information. This user id should be the primary key of both the `Users` table as the `VipUsers` table. Also, it should be a foreign key in VipUsers, referencing Users, so that you can not have an orphan VipUser record, without basic user information.

However, I would opt for a single table with a type and nullable fields. And I've got the feeling that that matches better with your current skill level as well.

Comment: I hope I did by adding this answer. :)

Comment: :) sorry dear. @GolezTrol i created 2 table . first table for vipuuser secong table for normaluser . I have 2 register form first register form for normaluser second register for vipuser. Vip user registration page has for example: name,surname,businessname,email,emailagain,password,country and city.

Comment: normal user registration form has, name, surname, email, emailagain, password, male, female, city and country. 
Normal user profile page is different then vipuser profile page. Normal user type is 0 vip user type is 1 is for different profile page.

Comment: i said create two table. first of all first table has in email password and type this table type is for normaluser. Second table has in businessname,name, surname,city,country, male and femaile. and also this table has type this type is for vipuser. type is 1 . It is 1 for vipuser. I want when vipuser registered his type is automatically 1 and also when normal user registered his user type is 0 . How can i do it.

Comment: i created 2 table because if i use one table all type is going to be 0 .

Comment: it is impossible or not. And if i can do this what can i do ? Can you help me please ?